# Tensorflow Lite GPU Support on object detector

Tags: android, tensorflow-lite

I have read the page https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/performance/gpu
And I was wondering if anyone can help me figure out how to shape my inputs to the "MobileNet SSD object detection". You only get a file: "mobile_ssd_v2_float_coco.tflite"

I've tried 320x320*3*4, because if I tried the "old" image resolution of 300x300 i got an error saying the arrays sizes didn't match, and the new size matches 320x320.

But now when I call run(input, output) the method never returns... no errors or anything :(

Does anyone have any advise, because I'm really grasping straws at the moment.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: did you find a solution to run this model on android using gpu?

Comment: also `runForMultipleInputsOutputs` is usually used in object detection examples

Comment: No, I got it semi-working if I disable the GPU delegate. But only to the point of getting output from the tensor. The GPU version of the detector has the last step removed, so it is not a drop in replacement in their example. Do you know what I mean? :)

Comment: @SteffenVangsgaard I'm also experiencing exact same issue. I changed to `320x320`, `quantized=false` and now get the error `Cannot copy between a TensorFlowLite tensor with shape [1, 2034, 4] and a Java object with shape [1, 10, 4].` Were you able to resolve the matter?

Answer (score 1):

You can check spec of some models by executing this commands in python [How to convert output from interpreter.run in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54716143/how-to-convert-output-from-interpreter-run-in-java/54732681#54732681) Printing input_details results in:

```
[{'name': 'normalized_input_image_tensor', 'index': 306, 'shape': array([  1, 320, 320,   3], dtype=int32), 'dtype': <class 'numpy.float32'>, 'quantization': (0.0, 0)}]
```

array shape [1, 320, 320, 3] so input must be image 320x320.
Output details:

```
[{'name': 'raw_outputs/box_encodings', 'index': 307, 'shape': array([   1, 2034,    4], dtype=int32), 'dtype': <class 'numpy.float32'>, 'quantization': (0.0, 0)}, {'name': 'raw_outputs/class_predictions', 'index': 308, 'shape': array([   1, 2034,   91], dtype=int32), 'dtype': <class 'numpy.float32'>, 'quantization': (0.0, 0)}]
```

We have 2 outputs with following shape: [1, 2034, 4] and [1, 2034, 91]
So prepare 2 arrays with exact size, for example in java android

```
private float[][][] out1;
private float[][][] out2;
out1 = new float[1][2034][4];
out2 = new float[1][2034][91];
```

then add them to map example java:

```
private Map<Integer, Object> output_map = new TreeMap<>();
output_map.put(0, out1);
output_map.put(1, out2);
```

and run with:

```
tflite.runForMultipleInputsOutputs(input_data, output_map);
```

tflite - interpreter, input_data - converted image

You will have data in arrays. I assume that in out1 will be bounding boxes coordinates and in out2 classes/scores? You need to do some more testing.

Example code https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow/lite/java/demo/app/src/main/java/com/example/android/tflitecamerademo
Of course you need to make some changes, so it will work with object detection model.